# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sinh x}{x}\right)^{{1}/{x^2}}$

Tags: limits, hyperbolic-functions

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sinh x}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{x^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Use Squeezing. Note that $1\lt \frac{\sinh x}{x}\lt e^x$ when $x$ is large.

Comment: will you please give the steps by the method we usually solve limits

Comment: The hint is the simplest way I have thought of. We can alternately take the (natural) logarithm and use L'Hospital's Rule to show it has limit $0$, so our limit is $1$. But do try Squeezing, you will like it.

Comment: Give the steps by using l hospital rule,i know its easy,but i am not able to oluse the rule

Comment: The intention of this forum is not to do your whole homework for you, but to help when you are stuck somewhere. You demand here a complete solution of your homework question without contributing anything.